# retorno de valor en callback

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo una función que es de S3 de amazon, en un archivo llamado aws-s3.js.

```
            const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        const fs = require('fs');
        
        const AWSCredentials = {
            accessKey: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId,
            secret: process.env.AWSSecretKey,
            bucketName: 'YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME'
        };
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId: AWSCredentials.accessKey,
            secretAccessKey: AWSCredentials.secret
        });
        
        const uploadToS3 = (fileName) => {
            // Read content from the file
            const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName.path);
        
            // Setting up S3 upload parameters
            const params = {
                Bucket: AWSCredentials.bucketName,
                Key: fileName.name,
                Body: fileContent
            };
        
             s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
                    return data.Location;
                });
        };
        module.exports= uploadToS3;
```

necesito retornar a otro archivo (methods.js) el resultado de la ejecución de esta, es decir si hay un error me retorne un false o en el caso contrario me retorne el path en donde quedó el archivo para registrarlo en bd, dejo igualmente el codigo de methods.js

```
let _insert = async function (req, res, next){
            try{
                const { params } = req;
                if(typeof req.files.detalle_comercio_adherido === 'object'){
                    // await upload(req.files.detalle_comercio_adherido);
                     let upload = uploadToS3(req.files.detalle_comercio_adherido);
                        let result = await comAdhServices.insertComAdh(params,new_path);
                            if(result === null){
                                res.json(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
                                res.end();
                                return;
                            }
                            res.json(httpStatus.CREATED, result[0]);
                            res.end();
                    }
            }catch(err){
                res.send(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, JSON.stringify({Error: httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Message: constants.Error.INTERNALERROR}) );
            }
        };
```

Lamentablemente el valor siempre me llega como indefinido en la variable upload, como debería ser la manera correcta para poder capturar el valor retornado por la función de s3?

Comment: **no edites** tu pregunta añadiendo el código correcto, la solución se encuentra abajo y con eso basta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`upload` es undefined porque `uploadToS3` no retorna nada.
`uploadToS3` no retorna nada porque `s3.upload` tampoco retorna nada.

La función anónima (el callback, el segundo parámetro) la ejecutará S3 cuando la subida falle o tenga éxito. No tienes cómo saberlo de antemano, y tu variable `upload` no es reactiva ni contiene una referencia al callback. Por diseño es `undefined`.

Segundo, si la operación tiene éxito y devuelves la ruta, no hay nadie escuchando.  El retorno ocurre dentro del callback, no dentro de `s3.upload`. De igual manera, si algo falla, tu try/catch no lo atrapa, porque está fuera de su scope (sólo se podría atrapar en el evento global [unCaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)).

La solución corta (pero muy mala) es que `uploadToS3` acepte un segundo parámetro con el mismo signature `(err, data)` y que se le pase tal cual a `s3.upload`.

```
const uploadToS3 = (fileName, cb) => {
  s3.upload(params,cb);
};
```

Con eso el que llame a uploadToS3 es el responsable de manejar el resultado, mientras `aws-s3` no tiene por qué saber quién lo llama ni para qué. Solamente instancia el conector y pasa la posta.

Ahora `methods.js` tiene que manejar el resultado. Por ejemplo con:

```
uploadToS3(req.files.detalle_comercio_adherido,(err,data)=>{
    if(err) throw err // esto sí lo atrapa tu try/catch

    res.json(data);
});
```

Dije que era una muy mala solución, y es porque podrían ser no dos sino 5, 15 o 50 capas en esta "cebolla" de callbacks. Para eso se inventaron las promesas (y para muchas otras cosas en realidad). Es cosa de hacer:

```
 const uploadToS3 = (fileName) => {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    
         s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(data.Location);
            });
     });
 };
```

y con eso podrías volver a tu intento original:

```
 let fileLocation = await upload(req.files.detalle_comercio_adherido);
```